# Javascript function that changes background color over a period of time with setTimeout() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to create a function that changes every 15 seconds the background color, picking the colors from an array that restarts after being visited. In this way my function runs just one time, how can I make picking from array a loop?

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const colors = ['#83ACDE','#EDCA38','#A1B2C3','#3C2B1A'];
    function start(i){
      if(i < colors.length){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
          i++;
          start(i);
        }, 15000);
      }
    }
    start(0);
```

Comment: reset i after the color.length is reached

Comment: @Marco Lapomarda you are not close document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "reset" your `i` variable when you've exceeded the array length...

```js
const colors = ['#83ACDE','#EDCA38','#A1B2C3','#3C2B1A'];
$(function() { start(0); });
function start(i){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
    i++;
    if (i >= colors.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    start(i);
  }, 2000); // Changed to 2 seconds for example
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using CSS animation which is faster and more efficient.

```css
body {
  background-color: #83ACDE;
  animation: changeBackgroundColor 60s infinite;
}

@keyframes changeBackgroundColor {
  0%,
  24.99%,
  100% {
    background-color: #83ACDE;
  }
  25%,
  49.99% {
    background-color: #EDCA38;
  }
  50%,
  74.99% {
    background-color: #A1B2C3;
  }
  75%,
  99.99% {
    background-color: #3C2B1A;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler is to use the [modulo(remainder) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) over the array length, like so:

```
start ( (i + 1) % colors.length);
```

This not only increments as it goes back to 0 when `i + 1` is equal to `colors.length`.

```js
const colors = ['#83ACDE','#EDCA38','#A1B2C3','#3C2B1A'];
function start(i){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
    start((i + 1) % colors.length);
  }, 1000); //1 second here to be easier to see
}
start(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note how i also removed the `if` that tests if the `i` is a valid index, as it is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

While I also recommend simply resetting `i`, an alternative is to use the modulus `%`, ie:

```js
const colors = ['#83ACDE', '#EDCA38', '#A1B2C3', '#3C2B1A'];

function start(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
    i++;
    start(i % colors.length);
  }, 500); 
}
start(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Example</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is properly just need small modification.

```
const colors = ['#83ACDE','#EDCA38','#A1B2C3','#3C2B1A'];
const ColorLength=colors.length;
$(document).ready(() => {   start(0);});
 function start(i){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
 i++;
 if (i >= ColorLength) {
  i = 0;
 }
 start(i);
}, 1000); 
}
```

Comment: You should be able to refactor so that the setTimeout code only appears once.

Answer (score 0):

Reset `i` when the length of `colors` is reached:

```
function start(i){
  if(i < colors.length){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i]);
      i++;
      if(i == colors.length) { i=0; }
      start(i);
    }, 15000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is because the `if` condition ends the cycle when the `i` value is out of the range of the `colors` array.

You can fix this by using the modulo operator to divide the `i` value by the `length` or the array and use the remainder as the index. You can also tidy the logic to immediately set the first background colour. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const colors = ['#83ACDE', '#EDCA38', '#A1B2C3', '#3C2B1A'];

  function start(i) {
    $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[i++ % colors.length]);
    setTimeout(function() { start(i); }, 1000);
  }

  start(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(() => {
const colors = ['#83ACDE', '#EDCA38', '#A1B2C3', '#3C2B1A'];
var index = 0;

function start() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (colors.length == index) {
            index = 0;
        }
        $('body').css("backgroundColor", colors[index++]);
        start();
    }, 2000);
}
start();

})
```